# Add document location in SharePoint to a footer of a document

Tags: 2007, document-library

How can I add the location of a document in SharePoint, to a footer of a Word document automatically through templates, quick parts, or some other means.

I would like my users to be able to save documents onto SharePoint, and then have the location available when those documents are printed etc.

Comment: Word 2007, 2010, or some other version?

Comment: Answers below will work with 2007...just be aware that the value doesn't update automatically, so you probably want to add a macro to your template(s) so it is updated automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a Filename field to the footer, but it won't update automatically (...not even on initial save).  Here is a workaround for that from Microsoft:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/832897

Comment: Nice one Rob. Sounds like the more complete solution. +1

Answer (score 0):

This can be done very easily in Word.  In the footer section of the document, insert the FileName field.  You have the option to include the entire path or just the filename.  If you include the entire path, the url to the document will be displayed.